# Outlook Express To and From columns are blank - IMAP with GoDaddy email

Tags: outlook, imap, pop3

Maybe someone here has seen this before. Some of the emails in my users IMAP Mail store have fields that show up blank. But if I look at the actual email details, to and from are populated. But these emails have blank To and From columns. We recently moved from POP3 to IMAP on GoDaddy. Any ideas why? Thank you!

Comment: It would appear this is a limitation in Outlook Express. Switched the client to Thunderbird and the To/From are there. Perhaps the lack of support of OE 6 explains it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook Express 6 does not fully support IMAP email. Use Thunderbird email instead.